# How do you run monodevelop on CentOS 5.5

Tags: mono, installation, terminal, centos, monodevelop

Hi i have successfully installed monodevelop on CentOS 5.5 using the EPEL repo. However I do not know where is the program. I am not much of a linux guy. I tried typing `monodevelop` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `rpm -ql monodevelop` to see the list of files the package installed. If the list is long, `rpm -ql monodevelop | grep bin` ought to narrow down the list significantly.

[More details on using `rpm`](http://fedoranews.org/alex/tutorial/rpm/6.shtml).